# Opencart: Sorting large numbers of Product Options

Tags: java, php, opencart

I have been racking my brain trying to solve this problem, so any ideas or advice would be GREATLY appreciated!

I am building a store for an upholstery company who make custom upholstered bed heads etc.
There are 300 fabrics to choose from, which is fine - I have added all 300 fabrics and their swatches as an option.

My problem is 300 swatches makes for a very long and messy product page - I need to be able to sort these fabrics by colour, range and fabric type and by any combination of those. (eg blue linen premium fabrics). Basically the same as this site: http://www.heatherlydesign.com.au/product/astor

What I was trying to do was add 3 extra columns to the catalog > options section, to assign a colour, range and fabric type "category" to each fabric, as pictured below:

[Extra Columns in Options section](http://www.marketingmaintenance.com.au/webimages/ss2.jpg)

My hope was to add these three fields as 'tags' or 'categories' to each fabric option, so I could sort (by hiding and showing) them through javascript on the product page.

My PHP knowledge is pretty limited, I mean I can add things to a database and stuff, but editing all the required OC files is a bit beyond me!

I have searched the entire internet :P and I cannot find any extensions or info on how I would do this. Was hoping to find an extension that adds a column to the main options section (not the options tab when editing a product) and reverse engineer it, but no luck!

Any help would be amazing... this has been stressing me out all week. Alternatively, if anyone has any ideas on how else I might go about making the options sortable that would be so awesome.

Thanks for your time!

Josh

Comment: Unfortunately I doubt somebody will answer with the whole solution here. You now have two options: find a tutorial on how to add custom fields to a product in OpenCart and try to use the same approach on product options (same approach, different files) or hire some OpenCart developer that will do that for you.

Comment: But I must admit this is quite nice idea for an extension itself :-)

Comment: Looks like it's going to be another one of those weeks :/

Comment: Hi josh can drop me a message iv done something similar to this for a similar company including the swatches also a sample ordering system so if i can help i will

Comment: @Dava Gordon Thanks a lot man, but I managed to figure out a solution thankfully :)